# MVC ASP.NET Map routing is not working with form GET request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

In View-

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("PageName","ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
  <input type="hidden" name="categoryName" value="Insurance" />                        
  <input type="hidden" id="cityName6" value="Irvine" name="cityName" />
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Insurance" />
}
```

In RouteConfig-

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "SomethingRouteName",
                "{categoryName}/{cityName}/{page}",
                new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "PageName" }
);
```

I want url to appear like this - Insurance/Irvine/1
But its coming like this- ControllerName/PageName?categoryName=Insurance&cityName=Irvine&page=1

This works fine when I use hyperlink instead of form get method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Insurance", "PageName", "ControllerName", new{ categoryName = "Insurance", cityName = "Irvine", page = 1})
```

//URL shown: Insurance/Irvine/1  as expected.
But I have to use form GET method so this hyperlink way is useless.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing any route values to `Html.BeginForm`, so your rendered form element looks like this:

```
<form action="/ControllerName/PageName" method="get">

</form>
```

So when you click submit, it simply appends the values of the form as a query string.

To fix this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PageName", "Home", new {categoryName = "Insurance", cityName = "Irvine", page = "1"}, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Insurance" />
}
```

Comment: @Manish0890, What possible point is there in doing this as opposed to using a hyperlink?

Comment: Job requirement. This was just an simple example for me to understand its working. Now I can use it in real scenario.