# asp.net mvc route using form get with 2 action and same view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have url problem when doing search on page. So, I have Index View with a year textbox and a search button inside a form using GET method

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Service", new { Year = Model.Year }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Year" } })
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
        </div>
    </p>
}
```

I put Search as `actionName` in `BeginForm` because when redirect to Service/Index the service data should not be loaded at the first time. So, I'm using another Action, "Search" to handle this request, if the user doesn't enter the year then it will load all of the data, but if the user enter the year it will load the data based on the year.

Here is the controller to handle the request

ServiceController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new ServiceIndexViewModel();
    return View(vm);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Search(int? year)
{
    var vm = new ServiceIndexViewModel();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var list = await service.Search(year);
        vm.Services = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ServiceListViewModel>>(list);
    }

    return View("Index", vm);
}
```

and the custom route to handle the routing

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ServiceSearch",
    "Service/Search/{Year}",
    new { controller = "Service", action = "Search", Year = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// default route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

);

but I've got the url like this:

http://localhost:18132/Service/Search?Year= or    http://localhost:18132/Service/Search?Year=2017

and I want the url to be displayed like this

http://localhost:18132/Service/Search or http://localhost:18132/Service/Search/Year/2017

What's wrong with my routing? How to solve this?

Comment: Adding `new { Year = Model.Year }` as a route parameter is pointless since its the value of the input that will be bound. You submitting a form to a GET method which means that the value of the input will only ever be added as a query string value (the browser does not know anything about your server side route definitions. But you could use javascript to build the url and use `location.href=..` (and cancel the form submit)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah you're right but I've got that code from this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176634/mvc-asp-net-map-routing-is-not-working-with-form-get-request. It has the same problem, but why he can make it and I don't? What is the difference?

Comment: The accepted answer in that question does not have any inputs - its just posting back the hard-coded values for the route parameters (and the OP just had hidden inputs so having a form was just nonsense anyway)

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775445/mvc-html-beginform-different-url-schema/37809015#37809015) for an example (except that you handle the forms `.submit()` event and cancel it)

Comment: So does that mean, it's the behaviour of submitting using GET method and it always like that even if you add a custom route?

Comment: Yes, your route definitions are server side code - the browser has no knowledge of them. And its also defined in the HTML standards

Comment: Ok thanks @StephenMuecke for your explanation, and I will think about using javascript to build the url.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your route should be defined like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ServiceSearch",
    "Service/Search/Year/{Year}",
    new { controller = "Service", action = "Search", Year = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

But your problem is something else your code is not falling to this defined route and it falls to the default route. Make sure that the default route is bellow this route if it's still not working comment me here and I will tell you what I have in my mind.

Comment: I've replaced the routing and here is the result http://localhost:18132/Service/Search/Year?Year= if I don't type any Year and http://localhost:18132/Service/Search/Year?Year=2017 if I type a Year